# How to test dynamic web project?

Tags: java, jsp, testing, tomcat, servlets

I am working in an imported Web project in eclipse.

And I want work and test it in my local computer, so I do not want that some classes call web services or run some part of the code. What is the best way to inform the code that is running under test mode. Should I create one servlet just to put one test flag in the session context? Or should I call any servlet with a test flag directly in the query string like `http://testserver/application/servlet.do?teste=true` or there is another better way to do this. I just want to learn the best practices.

Comment: dont you have a staging/test/QA environment?

Comment: I will work just in my own machine because in the enterprise environment is very slow , so answering to your question i do not have  any other environment

Answer (score 1):

As happymeal aludes to, you may be better leaving all the code in place and making it call "test" versions of the web services that you mention.

But, to answer your question, you could have a static flag inside a "Configuration" class, and set that in various ways.
One way to set the flag would be to use -Dmycompany.Configuration.TestMode=true on your server command line.

Sample code:

```
public class Configuration {
  /**
   * Whether the app is in test mode. This can be set with a -D at startup or by some
   * other code calling "setTestMode".
   */
  private static boolean TEST_MODE = Boolean.getBoolean('mycompany.Configuration.TestMode');

  public static boolean isTestMode() {
    return testMode;
  }

  public static void setTestMode(boolean b) {
    testMode = b;
  }
}
```

To check whether you're in test mode, your code can call "isTestMode()" - simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a simple config properties file on my server somewhere with a value for "testing".  Maybe in a jndi properties file. Load the value at application startup. That way, if I want to switch from "testing" mode to "live" mode I can make the change without having to rebuild the application.